# Creating proc entry under parent folder

Tags: linux, file, linux-kernel

I want to create a proc entry under /proc/driver/  path,

I am using this code:

```
 struct file *fp = filp_open("/proc/driver",O_RDONLY,0);
 struct proc_dir_entry *parent ;
 parent =  PDE(fp->f_dentry->d_inode);
 filp_close(fp, NULL);
 proc_create("leds",0,parent,&proc_fops);
```

But when compile i got error :

```
error: implicit declaration of function ‘PDE’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

How can i fix this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you include the header for PDE?

Comment: @Xiaotian Pei : what is the path for PDE header?

Comment: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/internal.h#L80

Comment: i must include<fs/proc/internal.h>?

Comment: you can try it to see if it works.

Comment: i try but it can't find the internal.h file error: fs/proc/internal.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @Sam What is your kernel version?

Comment: @SamProtsenko It is 3.13.0-32-generic and it doesn't have internal.h file as suggested, but i solved the problem by fixed the Makefile to point to other lib. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include the header file contain PDE declaration?